# frame tick label

Tags: graphics

I am making a framed plot. I want to remove some of the tick labels but display all the ticks. For example, I want {-1,0,1} as the the tick labels on the y axis but want to display all the ticks between -1 to 1.I have done the following and the plot is showing only the mentioned labels and not the ticks between them.

```
FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 0, 1}, Automatic}, {{-2,-1,0,1,2}, Automatic}}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) (`FrameTicks` uses the same specification format) - you need to specify all the ticks you want, each with the appropriate label. If you don't want a label, you can use `""` or `Spacer[0]` as label specification.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the internal function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``

```
yticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity},
   "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {3, 10}] &;

xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
        "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {6, 5}] &;

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicks -> {{yticks, Automatic}, {xticks, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

If the horizontal plot range were `-Pi` to `Pi` the function `xticks` would have major ticks at `-3` and `3` in addition to your desired list of labeled ticks. You can remove the unwanted labels using `ReplaceAll`:

```
xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
   "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {6, 5}] /. {a : (3. | -3.), _, b___} :> {a, "", b}&;

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yticks, Automatic}, {xticks, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following workaround.

There is the possibility to put anything at at a specified tick. For that instead of figure specifying the tick you need to put a list: `{figure, what-you-want}`. For example, instead of your list `{-1,0,1}` you may put `{{-1,"a"},{0,"b"},{1,"c"}}` and you get a, b and c instead of -1, 0 and 1. More details you may find in Help.

Now to your specific task. Let us firsts make a list, lst1, with figures for ticks replaced by the empty strings:

```
lst1 = Table[{i, ""}, {i, -1, 1, 0.1}]

(*  {{-1., ""}, {-0.9, ""}, {-0.8, ""}, {-0.7, ""}, {-0.6, 
  ""}, {-0.5, ""}, {-0.4, ""}, {-0.3, ""}, {-0.2, ""}, {-0.1, 
  ""}, {0., ""}, {0.1, ""}, {0.2, ""}, {0.3, ""}, {0.4, ""}, {0.5, 
  ""}, {0.6, ""}, {0.7, ""}, {0.8, ""}, {0.9, ""}, {1., ""}} *)
```

Let us now replace the empty strings at -1, 0 and 1 to what you want to leave:

[image]

```
(* {{-1, "-1"}, {-0.9, ""}, {-0.8, ""}, {-0.7, ""}, {-0.6, 
  ""}, {-0.5, ""}, {-0.4, ""}, {-0.3, ""}, {-0.2, ""}, {-0.1, ""}, {0,
   "0"}, {0.1, ""}, {0.2, ""}, {0.3, ""}, {0.4, ""}, {0.5, ""}, {0.6, 
  ""}, {0.7, ""}, {0.8, ""}, {0.9, ""}, {1, "1"}}  *)
```

Now let us build a simple plot

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{lst2, Automatic}, {{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you.