# Frame Ticks and Tick Marks Issue

Tags: graphics, labeling, ticks

Following code from [frame tick label](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206537/frame-tick-label), with a slight modification in the `FrameTicks->{{}{}}`:

```
yticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {3, 10}] &;

xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {6, 5}] &;

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks}, {xticks, xticks}}]
```

The issue is that I get the same graph as obtained in the above link, but I also get the frame labels from -1 to 1 on the right y-axis and -2 to 2 on the upper x-axis. What I want is to get exactly the same tick markers as on the left y-axis and horizontal down x-axis, on right and top, but without numbers on them. In other words, how to get the same tick marks on all axis and only two axes numbered. Any suggestions on this, please?

**Edited**
I am trying the above code with a log-log scale and it fails to work. Could it be checked, please? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `FrameTicks -> {{yticks, Automatic}, {xticks, Automatic}}`?

Comment: With the "Automatic" choice, the tick marks are not the same on the "right" and "left" and on the "top" and "bottom".

Comment: what version/OS are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 10 on Mac

Comment: does it work if you add the option `FrameTicksStyle->{{Automatic, FontOpacity->0},{Automatic, FontOpacity->0}}` to `Plot[...]` in your code?

Comment: As a workaround, perhaps you could define a copy of your ticks where you remove the labels with `{a_?NumericQ, _, b___} :> {a, "", b}` (c.f. the end of kglr's answer in the linked [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206540/73380) ) So for example ```yticksBare = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][##, {3, 10}] /. {a_?NumericQ, _, b___} :> {a, "", b}&```

Comment: @kglr: sorry it does not work! One thing I want to clarify that I want to keep "yticks" on the left "y-axis" and "xticks" on the down "x-axis" as defined in the above code.

Comment: @Hausdorff: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Hausdorff: Could you please check above why does it not work with the "ListLogLogPlot", that is, frame tick markers with a log scale. Thanks!

Comment: @SciJewel At least in Mathematica 12.2 the method also works for `ListLogLogPlot` (in fact all `List*Plot` functions), and unfortunately I don't have version 10 at hand. Sorry :\

Comment: SciJewel, can you, please, provide the piece of code that you have tried with the Log-Log scaling? There are internal options for the undocumented function you have used for the ticks, and in those live options for log scaling; it would be helpful if you can please provide your code so that this question can be answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the option `FrameTicksStyle -> ({#, #} &@{Automatic, FontOpacity -> 0})` to make the top and right tick labels invisible:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks}, {xticks, xticks}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> ({#, #} &@{Automatic, FontOpacity -> 0})]
```

[image]

This works in Wolfram Cloud

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "Version 12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"
> ```

Also works in *Version 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Let us first define the ticks:

```
yLeft = Map[
   If[IntegerQ[#], {#, 
      Style[ToString[(#)], 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, {# // 
       N, ""}] &, Range[-11/10, 11/10, 1/10]];
yRight = Range[-11/10, 11/10, 1/10] /. x_?NumberQ -> {N[x], ""};
xBottom = 
  Map[If[IntegerQ[#], {#, 
      Style[ToString[(#)], 12, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, {# // 
       N, ""}] &, Range[-(13/5), 13/5, 1/5]];
xTop = Range[-(13/5), 13/5, 1/5] /. x_?NumberQ -> {N[x], ""};
```

Now we can plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yLeft, yRight}, {xBottom, xTop}}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: That's okay, but where is the log-log?

Comment: Your question contained no log-log plot