# Using Frame, display all of the ticks but labeling only one

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I have a figure displayed by the following code:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

However, I want the tick in the position y=0.6 to be labeled as L. To do this, I have:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{{{0.6, "L"}}, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

The thing is I want all of the other ticks on the left frame to be displayed without label, but I can't; it seems to be either all of the ticks with label or only one tick with my special label.

I found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206537/frame-tick-label) to be kind of helpful, but it is not exactly what I want and I'm able to get a grasp on it.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][min, max, {majorticks, minorticks}] `` produces desired number of major and minor ***unlabeled*** ticks in the range from `min` to `max`. Just append or prepend your list of desired ticks to the ticks produced by this function.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> 
  {{Append[{0.6, "L"}] @ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] &,
    None}, 
   {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Replace `Append[{0.6, "L"}]`  with `Append[{0.6, "L", {.03, .02}, {Thick, Red}}]` to get:

[image]